# Why does reading a large PNG file fail inside Photoshop panel?

Tags: javascript, photoshop

Inside of a custom Photoshop panel extension I've created, I am attempting to read the data from a PNG file that is larger than 64kb on the local file system. Using the CEP readfile, nodejs readfile or createReadStream, results in a buffer length of zero, or no data, as if the file was empty. This does not trigger any errors by any of the mentioned methods.

I've attempted to read the file in several formats that are available through the readfile methods. Reading the buffer directly and counting the length, reading as Base64, UTF8, etc. This doesn't make a difference. If the PNG file is above 64kb, it soft-fails to read the file, instead indicating it believes the file *has* no data.

Some additional details I've uncovered:

- This never throws an actual error from any of the above mentioned methods.
- The PNG file size has to be above 64kb to trigger the issue.
- JPGs can be any size and don't have the same problem. I tested JPG files as large as 1mb without issue.
- Changing the file format read by the stream does not make a difference.
- Doing a read of the large PNG immediately after reading a JPG in the same folder location **causes this problem to not occur**.
- This only happens with PNGs generated by Photoshop. I duplicated a PNG using a separate method, re-ran the program, and the error no longer occurred.

Code Sample:

```
var node_fs = require( 'fs' );  
var data = node_fs.createReadStream( pathToTheLocalFile, 'base64' );  

data.on( 'readable', () => {  
     var info = data.read();  
     b64 += info;
} );  

// This event never fires, which seems unusual.
data.on( 'error', () => {  
     for ( var p in arguments ) {  
          console.log( arguments[p] );  
     }  
} );  

// Once the read is done, this fires, and has no data.
data.on( 'end', () => {  
     // do stuff with the b64
};
```

If the file is unreadable, I would have expected an error message. That doesn't happen. Ideally, I would be able to read the contents of the file and manipulate that data as I need.

One final unusual note: if you attempt to recreate this and have the localhost panel developer tools open, the file read will work without issue. It only happens when DevTools is closed. Which is another strange phenomenon.

Comment: what you want to achieve by reading PNG files :D I've made a extension which can preview any layer by drag and drop basis and it works fine! i just loaded images from div rather than storing it as code :D

Comment: @DesignPhoenix I send the images from Photoshop to a remote endpoint. The images themselves are generated by the built-in PS Generator plugin. I've already solved the issue of creating, loading and moving the images to where I need them to go. Unfortunately this error is specifically related to reading 64kb+ PNGs from the file system.

Comment: well then it seems a WEIRD issue though. at first we can think that 64 KB is limit but if that is so but jpg is working fine as well as in developer tools too. can it be some sort of  CEP/CEF  issues from csInterface.js?

Comment: As the issue occurs regardless of whether I am using CEP or node.js to read the file, it seems unlikely that it's specific to csinterface.js. Definitely a weird issue!

Comment: I'll highly recommend you to post question in github directory to attract the devs :)